# Is there any file content search tool that decompresses JAR files before looking into it?

Tags: windows, grep, file-search, agent-ransack

I use Agent Ransack to grep entire directories. But it doesn't unzip JAR files before looking into them, is there any tool that does that?

Comment: find / -iname "*.jar" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 unzip -p | grep …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `unzip`:

```
unzip -p your_file.jar | grep "your_search"
```

From the `man` page:

```
-p     extract files to pipe (stdout).  Nothing but the file data is sent to
       stdout, and the files are always extracted in binary format, just as
       they are stored (no conversions).
```